# WordPress ACF option goup with gallery field on archive.php returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a small problem with ACF on the archive.php. I have a ACF group with some fields in it. For example a gallery field.

The problem is that the gallery field returns NULL, does anybody know how to fix this?

This line of code works and it returns the value. So I don't know why the gallery field isn't working

`<?php the_field('header_block_size', 'options');?>`

This is what I came up with.

```
         <section id="page-header" class="page-header page-header--<?php the_field('header_block_size', 'options');?>">
            <?php $images = the_field('header_block_images', 'options'); ?>
            <?php var_dump($images);?>
            <?php if($images): ?>
                <div class="page-header__carousel">
                    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
                        <div class="page-header__inner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($image) ?>')">
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="page-header__heading">
                        <h1 class="page-header__heading-title"><?php the_field('header_block_title', 'options');?></h1>
                        <div class="page-header__heading-border"></div>
                        <?php if(get_field('header_block_filter', 'options') === true): ?>
                            <div class="page-header__filter">
                                <?php echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter fields="post_tag" submit_label="Check out the tours"]'); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
            <?php endif ; ?>
        </section>
```

[This is the location setup of the ACF group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMDDi.png)

[This is image shows the outcome of the code, you can see it is NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaHgS.jpg)

I hope someone knows how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

I have edited the code with `<?php var_dump(get_fields());?>` instead of `<?php var_dump($images);?>` and it returns `array(1) { ["rating"]=> float(4) }`

I've also added a new image with the gallery field.

[image: Picture of the content I added to the gallery]

Comment: Change the gallery call to `get_field`.  Have you saved gallery images to the options page?

Comment: You have a mistake in your code, but even so you should still get something printed to the screen. As the above comment says, make sure you definitely have something saved in `header_block_images` in the options page. If you do, then replace your `var_dump($images);` with `var_dump(get_fields());` and update your answer with what it prints to the screen, so we can see more about what you are working with

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have edited the question with the results

Comment: The var_dump isn't showing any of the ACF fields so that's not helping. Everything must be in options so try this instead and hopefully that will show us what's in the head block: `<?php var_dump(get_fields('options'));?>`

Comment: I var dump what you did and this is what it returns. ```array(13) { ["header_block_filter"]=> bool(false) ["header_block_images"]=> bool(false) ["header_block_size"]=> string(5) "small" ["header_block_title"]=> string(8) ```

Comment: That doesn't look like the full array - it says there are 13 elements. Can you update your question to include it, the comments are limited in length and its not easy to read code in them. It does say `header_block_images`is false though, so that's where you problem is - its not the code (unless the images are somewhere else in the array), its the ACF setup. I can't help there I'm afraid as I can't see what way it is set up in the back end.